# Why did I install Chinese tokenization package but the terminator kept saying I should install them?

Tags: anaconda, tokenize, chinese-traditional

I try to run Montreal Forced Aligner in aligner environment. I ran the command

```
mfa align --clean input/ mandarin_taiwan_mfa mandarin_mfa output/
```

but the terminator said, "Please install Chinese tokenization support via `pip install spacy-pkuseg dragonmapper hanziconv`", so I did it.
However, when I ran the command
`mfa align --clean input/ mandarin_taiwan_mfa mandarin_mfa output/`again, the terminator still said, "Please install Chinese tokenization support via `pip install spacy-pkuseg dragonmapper hanziconv`". Why is this happening?

I want to run Montreal Forced Aligner with an acoustic file and the TextGrid